# Call Injected AngularJs Service In Controller From Blazor Within CustomElement/WebComponent

Tags: angularjs, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am using the new feature in Blazor WASM to create a custom element and I am rendering it within an AngularJs app

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.RegisterAsCustomElement<TestComponent>("test-component");
await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

The AngularJs controller, where you can see the injected services

```
angular.module("umbraco")
    .controller("BlazorDashboard", function ($scope, $location, userService, notificationsService) {
    var vm = this;
});
```

The HTML for this controller

```
<div ng-controller="BlazorDashboard as vm">
    <test-component></test-component>
</div>
```

The Blazor component is rendering fine and working as expected. However, I'm trying to figure out a way I could use the injected JS services from the AngularJS controller within the Blazor component? A method which works in the controller is the following method, which displays a popup JS notification.

```
notificationsService.error("There was an issue", "Failed");
```

I have tried doing the following in the Blazor component

```
[Inject]
public IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
public async Task ShowNotification()
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("notificationsService.error", "There was an issue", "Failed");
}
```

`<button @onclick="ShowNotification">Click me</button>`

But I get the following

> Could not find 'notificationsService.error' ('notificationsService'
> was undefined).

Is there a way I can pass this notificationsService into the component directly, maybe as a parametere? Or another way I could call it within the Blazor component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ideal, but the way around this is to pass the controller injected service to the window object and then you can call it via Blazor.

```
angular.module("umbraco")
    .controller("BlazorDashboard", function ($scope, $location, userService, notificationsService) {
    var vm = this;
    window.notificationsService = notificationsService;
});
```

Then call it in blazor like so

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("notificationsService.success", "Whoop", "notificationService called from Blazor");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be caused by the way you are doing dependency injection in angularjs.

Try this syntaxt instead, using $inject:

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller("BlazorDashboardCtrl", BlazorDashboardCtrl);

BlazorDashboardCtrl.$inject = [
   '$scope',
   '$location',
   'userService',
   'notificationsService'
];

function BlazorDashboardCtrl(
   $scope, 
   $location, 
   userService, 
   notificationsService
){
   var vm = this;
}
```

Please notice, I've changed the name BlazorDashboard to BlazorDashboardCtrl for convention.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Still get the same undefined error.